# I need to set next button as disabled till any radio button got selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, radio-button

In my use case i need to set Next button from a popup is disabled in default till any one of the radio button got selected.

Need to achieve this in Ember.Js

My hbs code (for that popup):

```
{{! To list all accounts in popup }}
<div id="listAllAccounts" class="modal animated fadeInUp modal-pop downloadAsPopup">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" {{action 'clearModal'}}>&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">List of accounts</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="textGroup">
          <h2 class="primaryTitle">Select an account.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modalTableHolder">
          <table class="primaryListTable" id="AccountsInfo">
            <thead>
              <td class="tablestyle5">Account ID</td>
              <td class="tablestyle5">Account Name</td>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {{#each model.integration as |list index|}}
                <tr>
                  <td class="tablestyle5"><input type="radio" name="accounts" class="messageCheckbox mt6 mR5" data-acc-name={{list.ACCOUNT_NAME}} value={{list.ACCOUNT_ID}}>{{list.ACCOUNT_ID}}</td>
                  <td class="tablestyle5">{{list.ACCOUNT_NAME}}</td>
                </tr>
              {{/each}}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="text-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" {{action 'clearModal'}}>Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" {{action 'showContainerPopup' 'clearModal'}}>Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{! To list all accounts in popup Ends }}
```

JS code:

```
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
          new URI(Abc, this.get('currentOrg.ABC_ID'), Project, this.get('defaultProject.PROJECT_ID'), Integration)
          .addQueryParam('email', this.get(email))
          .GETS()
          .then(function(res) {
            if(res.length !== 0){
              var sett = projectObj.get("INTEGRATION");
              self.set("model.integration", res);    //this is where i set data to that popup
              common.hideModal("loadingPopup");
              common.showModal("listAllAccounts");  
            } else {
              common.hideModal("loadingPopup");
              options.content = i18n("enable.integration.noaccount.error");
              options.type = 'warning';
              dialog.showCard(options);
            }
          });
```

This is the popup. I need to disable the next button until anyone selects any one radio button. If radio button is checked i need to enable next option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you can disable your button using

```
disabled="disabled"
```

when pop is appear and add extra class for next button `btn-next`.

And check if radio button is checked or not to enable your button.

```
 $(document).on('click',"input:radio[name='accounts']",function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(".btn-next").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I also tried this but how to trigger this condition while clicking radio button. I wrote action in "Next" button. Not written any action while clicking radio button?

Comment: after ` common.showModal("listAllAccounts");` you can check your condition.

Comment: Yeah it disables the Next button but while selecting any radio button it does not enabled. Because the values of radio button is rendered once while construction popup. The values didn't rendered again while selecting the radio button. That's why it wouldn't entered the condition.

Comment: Sorry dude, It is not working. It remains disable always.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.change()` or `.one("change")` to check whether they select yet.

```
 $(".text-right button:last").prop("disabled", true); // disable the button
 $('input[type="radio"]').one("change", function () {
         $(".text-right button:last").prop("disabled", false); // enable it;
 });
```

Comment: When to trigger this code and how? I didn;t wrote any action in radio buttons. Then how do i observe changes from radio button like it is checked or not

Comment: You can trigger the jQuery code in this conditional statement `if(res.length !== 0){` or even in the hbs code. The .change() would determine if the input is selected or not

Comment: It wont works. The Next button is enabled always. Even if i didn't selected any radio button

Comment: Did you try to wrap in `<script>$(document).ready(function(){// code above });</script>` and put at the end of hbs code (popup html) ?

Comment: I added your code at the end of hbs. but it still won't works